# NDK replacement of deprecated `malloc_usable_size`

Tags: android, android-ndk

I need to port a large cross platform code which consists of the **`malloc_usable_size()`**. 
But, Seems like it was **deprecated** (read [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/android-ndk/malloc_usable_size/android-ndk/VCEUpMfSh_o/S5DHm72VsMcJ) and [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/android-ndk/malloc_usable_size/android-ndk/t4q4pkiv4iw/484jdEhIzlsJ)).

Seems like I'm not the first one that needs it ([1](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/android-ndk/malloc_usable_size/android-ndk/075hDVbaGx4/7C2IRtsff6MJ) & [2](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/android-ndk/malloc_usable_size/android-ndk/NdrxRwscmwc/mtAVBopGxIkJ)), but still no answer.

**What alternative can be used to replace that method?**

Thank you!

Comment: The API was a platform-specific feature to allow code to fully use allocated space, including parts that were effectively lost in the "rounding error".  It sounds like some code was using it instead as a way to remember how large an allocation was, perhaps as a way to avoid tracking the size separately.  Is that the issue you're facing?

Comment: @fadden Thanks for your response! Indeed that's exactly what I'm facing. I am tracking all memory allocations to know if I'm about to exceed my general limit. 
Any ideas on alternative to that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There should be `dlmalloc_usable_size` function in the NDK.
But generally somebody inside google decided that `malloc_usable_size` is not needed anymore and removed it from the standard linux api, so I'm not sure how it would be in the never NDK versions. Maybe `dlmalloc_usable_size` will be also removed.